# Opensaml : Signature outputs with empty reference URI

Tags: java, opensaml

How can I set the URI of the Reference node under SignedInfo, under Signature. Why does it not pick the value of the ID from Response object when I sign it?

## Here is my code:

```
QName respQName = new QName(SAMLConstants.SAML20P_NS,Response.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_LOCAL_NAME, "samlp");
Response resp = new ResponseBuilder().buildObject(respQName);
resp.setID(uuid);
//resp.set .......

Signature signature = (Signature) Configuration.getBuilderFactory().getBuilder(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME)              .buildObject(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
signature.setSigningCredential(signingCredential);
signature.setKeyInfo(new SAMLResponseGenerator().getKeyInfo(signingCredential, null, uuid));
assertion.setSignature(signature);
resp.getAssertions().add(assertion);
Signer.signObject(signature);
marshallerFactory = Configuration.getMarshallerFactory();
Element responseTxt = marshallerFactory.getMarshaller(resp).marshall(resp);
System.out.println(XMLHelper.nodeToString(responseTxt));
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is facing the same issue: the reference uri seems to come in only when the actual  response object is marshalled & then signed. Only signing it without marshalling is not enough. In my case, Iam encrypting the assertion after signing it.

```
Element  responseTxt = new ResponseMarshaller().marshall(resp);  
Signer.signObject(signature);                  
EncryptedAssertion encryptedAssertion = getEncryptedAssertion(resp.getAssertions().get(0), credential);
resp.getAssertions().clear();
resp.getEncryptedAssertions().add(encryptedAssertion);
```